# Android Studio: Error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: android-studio

I am using Windows 7 64bit and switched to the latest Android Studio and I am getting this error with:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':myproject'.
> Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\me\Apps\Android\android\myproject\myproject:facebook-sdk\bolts-android-1.1.2.jar'.
>
> Error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

This occurred for versions
Android Studio: 1.0.1
Gradle: 2.2.1

Comment: The colon in the middle of that path is pretty suspicious. You should figure out what's causing it and put a stop to it.

Comment: The problem is that the directory name is invalid, as @Scott indicated. Windows does not allow colons (`:`) in a filename, as that is the drive separator. `C:` is valid, `myproject:facebook-sdk` is not, as `myproject:` is not a valid drive letter.

Comment: Yes Scott Barta you are right my windows 7 machine was not smart enough to ignore this colon, removed it and now it started working for me. On Macbook it was all ok with or without.

Answer (score 4):

This issue will come if the syntax is mismatched. Please find below scenario,
I did one mistake in my build.gradle file

```
    compile files(':libs/lib_ivy_android')
```

and I modified later like below

```
    compile files(':libs/lib_ivy_android.jar')
```

then also I got same error I did some R&D about this then finally I modified like below then no error

```
    compile files('libs/lib_ivy_android.jar')
```

So this might be a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

@ScottBarta and @KenWhite solved this in the comments (the `:` is invalid in a filename)

> The problem is that the directory name is invalid, as @Scott
>   indicated. Windows does not allow colons (`:`) in a filename, as that is
>   the drive separator. `C:` is valid, `myproject:facebook-sdk` is not, as
>   `myproject:` is not a valid drive letter.

Other [invalid letters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are

> ```
> < (less than)
> > (greater than)
> : (colon)
> " (double quote)
> / (forward slash)
> \ (backslash)
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
> ? (question mark)
> * (asterisk)
> ```

As the OP said, just remove it:

> removed it and now it started working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error, because I add same library in both .jar and also  dependency

**Like this**

[image]

Comment one .... Happy coding  :]

Comment: You should be posting your picture as code as this answer could be useful to someone in the futur

Comment: @rak007 That's the true, but how can i highlights the code lines in case of code format !!!