# Android Studio Importing

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, import, java-io

I have some problem with importing an Eclipse project into Android studio. When I import i get this message[image]

> C:\Users\kabinra\Desktop\ChernivtsiTransport:
>   java.io.IOException: Syntax error in the file name, directory name, or volume label

I do not know what this error means and which part is problematic. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Google can help](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%20the%20filename%20directory%20name%20or%20volume%20label%20android%20studio) and leads you to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829542/android-studio-error-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-in):

Could it be that your file is really named `ChernivtsiTransport:`?
In that case, as said in [the question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31317643/1587329), you need to rename the file and remove the `:`, as it seems to be a [reserved character.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Avoid these:

> ```
> < (less than)
> > (greater than)
> : (colon)
> " (double quote)
> / (forward slash)
> \ (backslash)
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
> ? (question mark)
> * (asterisk)
> ```