# Not able to build apk in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build apk in android studio but getting below error:

```
Cause: property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory,
 transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory,
 fixed(class
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$FixedDirectory,
 E:\project\TestApp\App\build))))\AndroidManifest.xml (The filename,
 directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

I am using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2` and android studio version is 3.3.2. I think I updated studio after this issue start occurring, earlier I was able to build. Can anybody suggest how this error can be resolved.

Comment: delete your build folder , clean project and try again . Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` here

Comment: Try that already did not help.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart, after deleting build folder

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Tried that also did not work.

Comment: @ManoharReddy AndroidManifest.xml is large size. Which part I should paste here.

Comment: I think it won't be a problem, if it's of any size

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32005990/3111083

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following

- make sure your classpath and dependencies upto-date in gradle
- check the resource folders that are mapped correctly in manifest file
- Invalidate caches and restart (File -> Invalidate caches and restart)
- clean project and rebuild